# Azure Stream Analytic always got same 'OutputDataConversionError.TypeConversionError', even I remove the datetime column in the Synapse DW sql pool,

Tags: azure, azure-stream-analytics

Always got same 'OutputDataConversionError.TypeConversionError' , even I remove the datetime column in output in Synapse DW sql pool, and got same error after delete and recreated stream analystic.

Stream Input is event hub, get dignostic log from azure sql database. Tested pass.
Stream output is a table in azure synapse analystic DW sql pool. Tested ok.
Query is like:

```
SELECT
Records.ArrayValue.count as [count],
Records.ArrayValue.total as [total],
Records.ArrayValue.minimum as [minimum],
Records.ArrayValue.minimum as [maximum],
Records.ArrayValue.resourceId as [resourceId],
CAST(Records.ArrayValue.time AS datetime) as [time],
Records.ArrayValue.metricName as [metricName],
Records.ArrayValue.timeGrain as [timeGrain],
Records.ArrayValue.average as [average]
INTO
OrderSynapse
FROM
dbhub d
CROSS APPLY GetArrayElements(d.records) AS Records
```

the query passed the test run. but stream job got into degraded state. and got error:
Source 'dblog' had 1 occurrences of kind 'OutputDataConversionError.TypeConversionError' between processing times '2021-11-12T05:28:08.7922407Z' and '2021-11-12T05:28:08.7922407Z'.

But even I deleted the stream job, drop the [time] column in output table, remove the "CAST(Records.ArrayValue.time AS datetime) as [time], " in the query statement, and recreated a new stream job, still got same error?

Part of the Activity log:
"ErrorCategory": "Diagnostic",
"ErrorCode": "DiagnosticMessage",
"Message": "First Occurred: 11/12/2021 7:39:12 AM | Resource Name: dblog | Message: Source 'dblog' had 1 occurrences of kind 'OutputDataConversionError.TypeConversionError' between processing times '2021-11-12T07:39:12.8681135Z' and '2021-11-12T07:39:12.8681135Z'. ",
"Type": "DiagnosticMessage",

Why? is there a hidden cache I can not clean?

Comment: Can you try to explicitly cast all columns and not only the date time? I’m wondering if the error message is misleading us here. Could you also please share the schema of the destination table? Please note that datetime in ASA is actually datetime2 in SQL.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like a [bug in the output adapter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/606514/stream-analytics-sql-output-and-column-order-in-sa.html) is provoking that issue. While the fix is rolling out, you can re-order the field list to match the column order in the destination table.